# mod_rewrite not working correctly locally

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following lines in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

#Shopping Redirects
RewriteRule ^shopping-bag?$ cart.php
RewriteRule ^checkout?$ checkout.php
RewriteRule ^product/([^/\.]+)/?$ product.php?fine_leather=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Now, all of this works great on the production server, (last line will appear as http://www.domain.com/product/this-is-a-product) but locally, the first two lines work fine but the last doesn't. It doesn't seem to passing the GET variable :(

Any ideas/suggestions to fix this? I need to get the pretty URL's fixed but don't really want to work on the server until I know that they are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteRule ^shopping-bag?$ cart.php [L]
RewriteRule ^checkout?$ checkout.php [L]
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)$ product.php?fine_leather=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: still no joy i'm afraid :(

Comment: Just added the first parts, there are a few other redirects going on but all these are simple redirects, nothing that needs slugs etc.

Comment: Sincerely, I don't see where the problem come from.

Comment: Nor do I, another one of my colleagues has the same issue :/ thanks for taking a look though. Appreciate it!